# Get record from table Based on cuurent date for user who works between two dates [10 pm of 7/8/2022 to 5 am of 7/9/2022] Carbon larave 6l php

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, timezone, php-carbon

I have table with name `attendance` in which user have to insert his `start_time` and `end_time` . Now both columns `start_time` and `end_time` have same datatype which is `datetime`. I am using [php-carbon](/questions/tagged/php-carbon) to store `start_time` and `end_time` .Time is being stored in UTC format . I am not allowed to change this table design and also not allowed to change `start_time` and `end_time` datatype. I have to create filter to get today's attendance record.

My problem is that I have to compare today's date with date stored in `start_time` to fetch the record. Now the problem is that if a users' `start_time` is 23-00-00pm of 7/8/2022 and they still continue their work till 09-00-00 am of 7/8/2022, then my filter will fail because I am using `carbon::today` or `carbon::now` to compare date with a date which is already stored in `start_time`. Then how I can get current record using today's date if the time has shifted from one day to other. I will have to use carbon because user timezone also matters. Means `start_time` is being stored in UTC format but we have calculated to show `start_time` to user according to their timezone. Again my question is simple:  how to get a *today's attendance* record for a user  using `start_time` column in which time has already been  stored in previous date but user is working between the two dates eg as a night shift. My code:

```php
    public function today_Attendance($user_id, $shift_id)
    {
        $todays_attendance = \App\EmployeeWorkSchedule::where('work_schedule_time_id', $shift_id)
                   ->where('user_id', $user_id)
                   ->whereDate('start_at', carbon::now())
                   ->first();
        return $todays_attendance;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the exact start and end you want and filter on the intersection:

```
$timezone = 'America/Toronto';
$start = Carbon::parse('2022-07-08 22:00', $timezone)->utc();
$end = Carbon::parse('2022-07-09 05:00', $timezone)->utc();
$todays_attendance = \App\EmployeeWorkSchedule::where('work_schedule_time_id', $shift_id)
    ->where('start_time', '<', $end)
    ->andWhere('end_time', '>=', $start)
    ->first(); // or ->get() to get them all
```

Note: `P1 start < P2 end AND P1 end >= P2 start` gives `true` if and only if P1 overlaps P2.

Comment: i have already mentioned that i have to fetch record  by comparing now date with date which has already been stored into table start_time coulmn ? now you are giving static value to the  $start column ok but how  could i get start_time value  by comparing by comparing date which has been shift to the next day plz read the post again and thanks for your reply i am waiting mate

Comment: Your column is a datetime and you can pass the precise start and end, so shift to the next dat is absolutely not an issue. It's like having 2 timestamps. You obviously can replace the static string with any variable, you just have to properly format them and take the timezone into account, that's why I put a variable for that in the example.

Comment: sorry  but your solution is not addressing my problem i think its totally different scenario you are talking